# How to use functions in other py files that depend on the objects in the current py file?

Tags: python, numba

I am new to python and trying to figure out how to organize my codes into several py files.

For example, suppose that I would like to organize my codes into main.py, set_param.py, gen_more_params.py, funs.py, et cetera with the following process in mind:

1. main.py's purpose is to run other py files and to do final calculations.
2. set_param.py sets initial parameters and stores them in some classes.

- e.g. running set_param.py sets a = 1 and b = 2 and stores them into Par.a and Par.b.

3. gen_more_params.py generates additional parameters by using functions in fun.py with parameters in set_param.py

- e.g. I have (x, y) in main.py and add(x, y) = Par.a*x + Par.b*y in fun.py. Running gen_more_params.py calculates c = add(x, y) and adds it to Par.c.

4. "main.py" does the final calculation with "Par" calculated from set_param.py and gen_more_params.py.

During the process, I would like to utilize "numba", which does not seem to support functions whose arguments include class.

What would be best way to write the code in this situation?

I initially consider making a list "Par", adding stuffs into the list, and calling objects in list like a = Par[0] in every function, but it doesn't seem handy b/c the number of parameters exceeds 50.

I also thought about using dictionary, but numba does not support dictionary with different types of objects in it.

I also thought about using global, but declaring global in every object seems too burdensome.

I would really appreciate if experienced python users could give ideas on how to approach this problem.

Comment: Are you having a circular import issue? In that case, you can import the module rather than individual functions for it. Please include the code for both modules.

Comment: I don't have a circular import issue. I actually tried to import the module "set_params" and use set_params.a and set_params.b. But the problem is that "numba" does not support functions that use modules as arguments..

Comment: It should still let you do that if you keep `nopython` off so it can still use the interpreter for some things.